# Firestore listener data usage

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a question about the bandwidth / data usage of a Firestore listener.

I know Firestore will only give the updated documents once it's listening.

Let's say a single document is 0.3 mb. If it gets updated frequently, does the listener has to download the document (0.3 mb) every time or will it only download the "new/updated" data.

This would make a difference for the end-user who is maybe using 4g.
I use Flutter in combination with Firestore.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Every time a document is updated from an active listener, the **entire** contents of the document are transferred with each update.  It does not transfer only the fields that changed.